# nth-child and nth-last-child not working together

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of thumbs...

```
<div class="projects-wrapper">
     <ul>
          <li class="project">
```

...and created a condition to change the margin of every fourth item in the list:

```
.projects-wrapper .project:nth-child(4n+4){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Now I need to change the margin of the last four items:

```
.projects-wrapper .project:nth-last-child(-n+4){
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

But these two conditions are not working together. Just separately

Comment: In which browsers do you experience the problem? It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/fFKFD/

Comment: I'm working on Chrome. This is very strange. The same code works outside the site. It is possible that another css condition is interfering?

Comment: I'm experiencing a very odd bug in JS Fiddle using Chrome.  When I initially load @Nix JS Fiddle it works as intended.  If I then hit RUN, it highlights the first, second and 12th LI's instead of the last 4.  I can reproduce in my own fiddle.

Comment: For me JS Fiddle works fine. In my code, I try to remove all class selectors and use just ul li.nth-last-child. But didn't work

Comment: I think your best chance here, is to study the computed styles, and where they inherit from. It's quite possible, that there's some other style that's messing with you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your css selectors so that `nth-last-child` comes before `nth-child`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fFKFD/2/

Comment: Nothing happens. And I discover that the nth-last-child selector is applied on the second and on the last list item.

Comment: we're seeing two different things then. maybe this will demonstrate it better: http://jsfiddle.net/fFKFD/3/ ...or maybe I don't understand the problem...